# Manhwa where a demon lord is reincarnated as human and has to fight his killer's brother

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

The demon lord is a goat looking creature on the final floor of a dungeon/tower and is very over-powered. He gathers drops like smartphones and starts wanting to be a human.

When he is killed/kills the final human to appear, who had white hair, he's reincarnated as a weak human who people mistake for the hero who killed the demon lord. He's a miner and then gets recruited to become a demon hunter and has a fight with the actual hero's brother, who also has white hair, on Jeju island?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Answer (score 1):

From your story description, it's match with a manhwa called ***[I Used to Be a Boss](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/pif01fy/i-used-to-be-a-boss)***. The boss (mc) also wants to become human, and after doing so, he lives as miner.

From Baka-Updates:

> Baphomet, boss of the Tower of Abyss, is reborn as a human after becoming envious of the hunters who are always trying to kill him. In his newfound form, Baphomet is free to seek new forms of entertainment in the outside world.